# Problem receiving path as input from the user

Tags: rust, input, rust-cargo

**UPDATE**:

*Solution*: The problem was not something going wrong on the code, it was the logic that I was using, to create a new name I was doing the following:

```rust
let mut new_img_prefix: String = String::from("new_");
    new_img_prefix.push_str(&original_img_path);
    let mut new_path_string: String = String::new();

    for (i, c) in new_img_prefix.chars().enumerate() {
        if c == '/' {
            new_path_string = new_img_prefix.replace(&new_img_prefix[4..i + 1], "");
            break;
        }
    }
```

This created a problem because paths can have multiple slashes (/), instead I solve this problem by creating a random string that would work as the new name of the file, and therefore the path:

```rust
let mut rand_string: String = thread_rng()
       .sample_iter(&Alphanumeric)
       .take(10)
       .map(char::from)
       .collect();
   rand_string.push_str(".png");
```

I'm having trouble creating a Rust program, the program is supposed to receive a path (path to an image) as an input, the problem is that although I am putting the path correctly Rust panics and says that the path that I've provided doesn't exist.

*Original Problem*

```
thread 'main' panicked at src\main.rs:22:60:
Failed to open: IoError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the file specified." })
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
             at /rustc/82e1608dfa6e0b5569232559e3d385fea5a93112/library\std\src\panicking.rs:645
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/82e1608dfa6e0b5569232559e3d385fea5a93112/library\core\src\panicking.rs:72
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/82e1608dfa6e0b5569232559e3d385fea5a93112/library\core\src\result.rs:1653
   3: enum2$<core::result::Result<enum2$<image::dynimage::DynamicImage>,enum2$<image::error::ImageError> > >::expect<enum2$<image::dynimage::DynamicImage>,enum2$<image::error::ImageError> >
             at /rustc/82e1608dfa6e0b5569232559e3d385fea5a93112\library\core\src\result.rs:1034
   4: ascii_creator::resize_img
             at .\src\main.rs:22
   5: ascii_creator::main
             at .\src\main.rs:16
   6: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<void (*)(),tuple$<> >
             at /rustc/82e1608dfa6e0b5569232559e3d385fea5a93112\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:250
   7: core::hint::black_box
             at /rustc/82e1608dfa6e0b5569232559e3d385fea5a93112\library\core\src\hint.rs:286
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\ascii-creator.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

This is the code that I'm using right now:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Please enter the name of the image you want to convert: ");

    let mut raw_path: String = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut raw_path)
        .expect("Error obtaining path");
    let path: &str = raw_path.as_str();

    let result = resize_img(path);

    println!("Exited process with: {:?}\n\n", result);
}

fn resize_img(original_img_path: &str) -> String {
    let img: DynamicImage = image::open(original_img_path).expect("Failed to open");
}
```

Comment: It tells you the file you specified could not be found. Make sure the path is correct (relative vs absolute path) and that the you have the correct access to the directory.
It would help to know which operating system you use

Comment: Instead of taking input like this, there's a *strong* convention to leverage command-line arguments, as in [`Clap`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/). Programs that force "interactive" input like this are *extremely* annoying to use as they are often very fussy to script.

Comment: The duplicate applied to your case: `let path: &str = raw_path.trim();`

Comment: PSA: You can call `resize_img(&raw_path)` and the ref will be converted as necessary. You can also define your receiver as `img_path: impl AsRef<str>` which makes it more flexible, as `img_path.as_ref()` will convert `&str` or `String` or whatever as necessary.